# Why there are a gap between two DIV which margin are 0

Tags: html, css

I have a very easy `HTML` like below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    div.framework {
      position: relative;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      border: 0;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
    }
    
    div.outside1 {
      position: relative;
      width: 20%;
      height: 30px;
      border: 0px;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="framework">
    <div class="outside1">DIV1</div>
    <div class="outside1">DIV2</div>
    <div class="outside1">DIV3</div>
    <div class="outside1">DIV4</div>
    <div class="outside1">DIV5</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I suppose the big `DIV` is `500px` and each child `DIV` is `20%`, so all the `DIV` should be in one line,
However, when Chrome display, the fifth `DIV` is in the second line. Would anyone know why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: I would use flexbox.

Comment: It's not necessary to use flexbox for this at all. @epascarello

Comment: @Rob you have one opinion and I have another.

Comment: @epascarello It's not a matter of opinion. We've been "fixing" such things for years, long before flex ever came out.